# Interrupting a function due to an event firing

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

Lets say I have the following function:

```
let x = 1
function countForever() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(x)
    x = x +1
    countForever()
  });
}
```

We also have an object which contains an EventEmitter called `e`. `e` has a state, and if that state doesn't equal 3, we wish to kill our function. We can achieve this with the following:

```
let x = 1
function countForever() {
  if (e.state != 3) return
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(x)
    x = x +1
    countForever()
  });
}
```

This works. However my real, non example function has a lot more steps in it, and I've found myself continually if checking the state, 8-10x through the function.

Given `e` is an EventEmitter I would like to catch these changes when the state changes and kill the function. Luckily, `e` already has an event we can listen for:

```
e.on('state_changed' , function(new_state) {
  // Kill countForever
})
```

How do I stop execution of this function from outside of its scope?

**EDIT**: I don't know why I wrote a sample function with a setTimeout, it seems I've been quite misleading. Here's a better one:

```
async function functionToKill() {
  if (e.state != 3) return
  thing1 = await functionThatTakesALongTime()

  if (e.state != 3) return
  thing2 = await secondFunctionThatTakesALongTime()

  if (e.state != 3) return
  thing3 = await thirdFunctionThatTakesALongTime()  

  //.....

  if (e.state != 3) return
  thing10 = await tenthFunctionThatTakesALongTime()  

}

// e is an event emitter
e.on('state_changed' , function(new_state) {
  // Kill/interrupt functionToKill
})
```

Effectively within the function I'm continually checking for the state over and over and returning if it's changed. I don't feel this is clean, and would like to do the equivalent of a `return` from an external call triggered by an eventEmitter

Comment: We need to see all the places  you think you have to check the state in your function.  Since node.js runs your Javascript code as single threaded, no outside events can run while a given piece of synchronous code is running.  The only place external events can run is when you wait for some asynchronous call like `setTimeout()`.  Then, other things get to run.  So, you may not have to check the state as many places as you think.  But, we'd have to see your actual code to advise further on that.

Comment: FYI, there is no way to "kill" a running function in Javascript.  First off, if it's running synchronously, nothing else can run while it's running anyway.  Second off, it is pauses execution for asynchronous things, then the only way to keep it from continuing when the asynchronous thing is done is to modify some state that affects the running of that function.  There is no such thing as a "Javascript function kill" like a "process kill" in the OS.

Comment: More detailed advice would require seeing the real code and the real situation - not just hypothetical to see what the best design options are.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00, I've added a better example with less confusion. I note you say that the JS is a single thread. If this is the case, how am I able to deal with events emitted whilst other code is running? E.g. if the example function in the question was running and I had a console.log() in the e.on function, it would log while the example function was still awaiting.

Comment: `await` and `setTimeout()` don't block.  Your function returns immediately when you call those and it goes back to the event loop and other things get to run.  Then, at some future time, the promise resolves or the timer fires, puts an event in the event loop and when that event gets to the top of the event queue, its callback gets called and then more code in your function gets to run.

Comment: FYI, in your `functionToKill()` example, it has to be declared `async` in order to use `await`.

Comment: I have all sorts of ideas for how to do this, but they ALL rely on seeing the real/actual code to know what would work best or be practical.  Showing only pseudo-code deprives you of the best possible ideas for your specific situation.  For some unknown reason, lots of people here think they should ask about an abstract problem and not show their actual problem/code.  In my experience here, that is not the most productive way to structure the question for either you or the people answering.

Comment: Ah I see thanks. `await` then effectively blocks the function but not the program. Unfortunately in this case there is no "real code", as I'm currently designing it. I'm using the [drachtio-srf](https://github.com/davehorton/drachtio-srf) library and building a function that plays back audio and prompts for input. If the caller has hung up during that (the state change), I don't want to keep attempting to prompt them and play back. The called `xFunctionsThatTakeALongTime()` are pretty irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't give us a whole lot to go on in your sample function, but here's an idea with that code.  You use a master promise that when rejected causes your sequence of `await` operations to abort:

```
// create deferred object so it can be rejected externally
Promise.Deferred = function() {
    if (!(this instanceof Promise.Deferred)) {
        return new Promise.Deferred();
    }
    let p = this.promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.resolve = resolve;
        this.reject = reject;
    });
    this.then = this.promise.then.bind(p);
    this.catch = this.promise.catch.bind(p);
    if (this.promise.finally) {
        this.finally = this.promise.finally.bind(p);
    }
}

// shared promise, when rejected our function stops advancing to more operations
let killPromise = new Promise.Deferred();

function raceKill(p) {
    return Promise.race(killPromise, p);
}

async function functionToKill() {
  try {
      thing1 = await raceKill(functionThatTakesALongTime());
      thing2 = await raceKill(secondFunctionThatTakesALongTime());
      thing3 = await raceKill(thirdFunctionThatTakesALongTime());

      //.....

      thing10 = await raceKill(tenthFunctionThatTakesALongTime());
  } catch(e) {
      // perhaps handle kill errors separately from actual function rejection errors
  }
}

// e is an event emitter
e.on('state_changed' , function(new_state) {
  // Kill/interrupt functionToKill
    killPromise.reject(new Error("state_changed"));
})
```

This structure with `Promise.race()` has a bit of an advantage in that it doesn't even wait for `functionThatTakesALongTime()` to finish before aborting (when your pseudo-code would have been able to check `e.state`).  It aborts immediately when you reject `killPromise`.  That other asynchronous operation isn't magically cancelled.  It will still do what it was going to do, but your `functionToKill()` won't wait around for it.

With actual code, there are probably more elegant ways to do this than using shared scope variables like `killPromise`, passing parameters, sharing something as object properties, etc...  But, hopefully this shows you the general idea.

Comment: Thanks so much for your code and patience @jfriend00! I think I get the concept, and I now have a rough version of this in my console. I'll do some reading on promise deferral so I understand it better!

Answer (score 0):

kill countForever? you can save the return value of setTimeout function with a variable such as timer, then clearTimeout(timer) when state_changed event fired. I don`t know if what I understand is right?

Comment: Sorry, adding the setTimeout was a huge misnomer. I've put in a better example function.